# Tools for Heap Profiling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools

How we can analyse and improve the performance using this tool?
Is there any right approach for doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

Go through the developer guides.here are some links.

[Heap Profiling](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling)

[Profiling heap usage](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html)